# Place plaintext right beside variables (without whitespace) in VS Code User Snippets

Tags: vscode-snippets

I would like to create a User Snipper in VS Code that is a combination of variables and plaint text. This can typically be achieved by combining variables and plain text with a whitespace between then. But I would like to ad a variable next to a text without a whitespace.

For Example, I would like to create the current timestamp like this:
`2022-02-19T21:02:24-0530`

Below is what I tried

```
$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATET$CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND-0530
```

Notice the `T` in between `$CURRENT_DATE` & `$CURRENT_HOUR`

OUTPUT:

`2022-02-CURRENT_DATET21:06:12-0530`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `$` symbol before the plain-text you want to add.

In this case, you need at add `$T` instead of `T`

```
$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE$T$CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND-0530
```

Note that `$T` will get considered as a [placeholder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholders), and it will be the last item selected while tabbing through the inserted snippet.

Answer (score 0):

@Gangula's answer sparked a thought that lead me to an completely automated solution.

Combining with the variable transform examples found in the [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets), you can do:

```
$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-${CURRENT_DATE/(.*)/$1T/}$CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND-0530
```

In short, I am regex selecting the date variable and replacing it with itself + 'T'.